# Scala, сортировка

Tags: scala

Дан текст и список слов (и то и другое в виде массива). Для каждого слова из данного списка нужно найти, сколько раз оно встречается в
тексте.
Эту задачу необходимо реализовать на языке программирования scala. Вроде не сложно. Помогите пожалуиста.

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать для решения проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Пусть у нас есть:

```
val text: List[String] = """
У меня живет козленок
 Я сама его пасу
 Я козленка в сад зеленый
 Рано утром отнесу
 Он заблудится в саду
 Я в траве его найду
""".replace("\n", "").split(" ").toList
```

Тогда смотри, есть простое решение, однако долгое решение

```
val result = desiredWords.map(word => word -> text.count(_ == word)).toMap

// result = Map(Я -> 3, в -> 3, его -> 2, Ленин -> 0)
```

Его сложность в данный момент составляет **O(N * T)**, где **N** - кол-во искомых слов, а **T** кол-во слов в тексте. Если ты собираешься искать все слова в тексте, то тогда такое вычисление займет **O(N^2)**, что как бы плохо.

---

Альтернативное решение:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val result = mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Int]

text.foreach{ word => 
  val nTimesFound = result.getOrElse(word, 0)
  result.update(word, nTimesFound + 1)
}
```

Давай пробежимся по тексту один раз и просто посчитаем кол-во всех слов в нужном тебе тексте. Для места хранения выберем `mutable.HashMap`. Согласно вот этому [источнику](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html), скорость добавления нового элемента или изменения элемента в этой HashMap составляет **eC** (амортизированная константа). Тогда конечная производительность **O(N)** - значительно лучше чем было раньше.

---

P.S. Вообще **изменяемые** коллекции в Scala не особо частый выбор разработчика, ведь у **НЕизменяемых** коллекций есть ряд преимуществ, а их недостатки легко компенсируются тем как разработчики обычно пишут код. Если надо, могу далее привести пример того как можно решить подобную задачу быстрее чем за **O(n^2)** на неизменяемой коллекции.